# Отсортируйте данный итератор таким образом, чтобы его элементы оказались в порядке убывания частоты их появления

Tags: python, сортировка, lambda, count

Функция должна выдавать такие значения:

```
frequency_sort([4, 6, 2, 2, 6, 4, 4, 4]) == [4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 2, 2]
frequency_sort(['bob', 'bob', 'carl', 'alex', 'bob']) == ['bob', 'bob', 'bob', 'carl', 'alex']
frequency_sort([17, 99, 42]) == [17, 99, 42]
```

Однако моя программа:

```
def frequency_sort(items):
    return sorted(items, key= lambda part: -items.count(part))
```

Выдает значения немного в другом порядке, например:

```
                ↓     ↓                         ↓     ↓
[4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 2, 2, 6] вместо [4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 2, 2]
```

При попытке добавления пред сортировки по дефолту, появляются проблемы с другими строками:

```
вместо ['bob', 'bob', 'bob', 'carl', 'alex'] выводит ['bob', 'bob', 'bob', 'alex', 'carl']
и вместо [17, 99, 42] выводит [17, 42, 99]
```

В общем лучший вариант это пока что тот, что я предложил выше (потому что проблема так только в одной строке), но как исправить это я ума не приложу

Comment: попробуйте сначала отсортировать  исходный список: `return sorted(sorted(l), key = lambda x: l.count(x), reverse=True)`

Comment: Так шестёрок и двоек одинаковое количество - как в таком случае их сортировать?

Comment: Уже пытался, сортировка создает проблемы в строковом типе, вместо ['bob', 'bob', 'bob', 'carl', 'alex'], выводит  ['bob', 'bob', 'bob', 'alex', 'carl']

Comment: Я не вижу проблем со строковыми списками. Если, конечно, вы не забыли упомянуть условие, что единичные вхождения не должны сортироваться.

Answer (score 0):

**Вариант 1**.
При одинаковом количестве элементы сортируются по возрастанию.

```
def frequency_sort(items):
    return sorted(items, key=lambda part: (-items.count(part), part))
```

```
[4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 6, 6]
['bob', 'bob', 'bob', 'alex', 'carl']
[17, 42, 99]
```

---

**Вариант 2**.
При одинаковом количестве элементы сортируются по порядку их следования в изначальном списке.

```
def frequency_sort(items):
    return sorted(items, key=lambda part: (-items.count(part), items.index(part)))
```

```
[4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 2, 2]
['bob', 'bob', 'bob', 'carl', 'alex']
[17, 99, 42]
```

Comment: Первый вариант не подходит, а вот второй то что надо, спасибо

Comment: Подскажите, в каком порядке выполняются  (-items.count(part), items.index(part)), сначала по индексам, потом по count?

Comment: В качестве ключа для сортировки выступает кортеж `(-количество, индекс)`. Соответственно, сортировка сначала по количеству, потом (при равном количестве) по индексу. Количество в кортеж идёт со знаком минус чтобы по нему шла сортировка по убыванию.

Comment: спасибо за помощь